# Which one is greater: $\sqrt7^{\sqrt3}\ $ or $\sqrt3^{\sqrt7}$ ??

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which one is greater:  $\sqrt7^{\sqrt3}\ $ or $\sqrt3^{\sqrt7}$ ??

DO NOT use calculator for predicting the answer.
DO NOT use logarithm.
Although $7^3\ $ is much less than $3^7\ $,it seems for such  irrational numbers the story might be different!!

Comment: You mean that you cannot compare $\frac{\log\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}$ with $\frac{\log\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{7}}$

Comment: Yes,just use simple algebraic techniques

Comment: You can't use logarithms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have
$$\sqrt7^{\sqrt3}>\sqrt3^{\sqrt7}$$
if and only if
$$7^{\sqrt3}>3^{\sqrt7}$$
if and only if
$$7^3>3^{\sqrt{21}}\ .$$
Since $7^3=343$ and $3^{\sqrt{21}}<3^5=243$, this is true.

Comment: Simple and brilliant ! :-$)$